# SAS - ftp and zip access method for data

Tags: sas

I am trying to use the ftp method to download a csv.gz. I would also like to unzip it with the zip access function. Is there a way of combining the two in one FILENAME STATEMENT.

```
FILENAME in ZIP "1763.csv.gz" GZIP LRECL=80 ;
```

Right now I have a local copy of the file but would instead like to pull it down through FTP.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this isn't doable in a single filename - you have to have two, one for the FTP and one for the Zip.

However, you can stream the file to a (temporary) local file, and then access that same file with `FILENAME ZIP`.  One paper that talks about this method is [this from SGF 2019](https://www.sas.com/content/dam/SAS/support/en/sas-global-forum-proceedings/2019/3015-2019.pdf); there are several other similar that have the same basic approach:

1. `filename ftp` to your ftp file
2. Data step to read in from `filename ftp` and write out using `recfm=n` to a (temporary) file
3. `filename zip` to read in the file created in step 2.